# Skipping to "catch" instantly after changing PHP code in Java Android application

Tags: java, php, android, mysqli

So I've been toying around in my mobile app that's supposed to let me register accounts and log in while getting some data from a database I've created. All was fine and dandy until I've changed my register.php file to check if the login is already taken and act accordingly to that. I tought I had a problem with my JSONObject and response, so I've tried using a string instead of boolean but still the program only goes into the try section to JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response); and then in instantly goes into the catch part of the code. I didn't change much, honestly i'd say that the code I've written now is cleaner than the one before but it doesn't work properly.

When I click the "Zarejestruj" button (polish for Register) data should be sent to database (which happens, but I can add an infinite amount of same logins for some reason) and the activity should go back to LoginActivity.java but it doesnt, it just sends the credentials into the database and stays there for infinity while allowing me to spam the hell out of the bRegister.

Here's the java code:

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
    Log.d("RA", "Zmienne");
    final EditText etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
    final EditText etSurame = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSurname);
    final EditText etLogin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etLogin);
    final EditText etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    final EditText etGroupNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etGroupNumber);
    final EditText etIndexNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etIndexNumber);

    final Button bRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRegister);
    Log.d("RA", "Po zmienncyh");

    bRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final String name = etName.getText().toString().trim();
            final String surname = etSurame.getText().toString().trim();
            final String login = etLogin.getText().toString().trim();
            final String password = etPassword.getText().toString().trim();
            final String groupNumber = etGroupNumber.getText().toString().trim();
            final String indexNumber = etIndexNumber.getText().toString().trim();



            Log.d("RA", "Przed wywołąniem responseListener");
            Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d("RA", "Response");
                    Log.d("RA", response);
                    Log.d("RA", "onResponse");
                    try {
                        Log.d("RA", "Try");
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        Log.d("RA", "ObiektResponse");
                        String success = jsonResponse.getString(response);
                        if (success == "success") {
                            Log.d("RA", "Success");
                            Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                            RegisterActivity.this.startActivity(intent);

                        } else {
                            Log.d("RA", "Error");
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage("Register Failed")
                                    .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                    .create()
                                    .show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.d("RA", "catch");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
            Log.d("RA", "Wykonało się");
            RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(name, surname, login, password, groupNumber, indexNumber, responseListener);
            Log.d("RA", "queue");
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(RegisterActivity.this);
            Log.d("RA", "registerRequest");
            queue.add(registerRequest);
            Log.d("RA", "Koniec");
        }
    });
}}
```

And here is my Register.php file:

```
require("Password.php");

ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "id2147309_javaprojekt123", "javaprojekt321", "id2147309_javaprojekt");

if($mysqli->connect_errno){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

if(isset($_POST["name"]) && isset($_POST["surname"]) && isset($_POST["login"]) && isset($_POST["password"]) && isset($_POST["groupNumber"]) && isset($_POST["indexNumber"]))
{
$name = $_POST["name"];
$surname= $_POST["surname"];
$login = $_POST["login"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$groupNumber = $_POST["groupNumber"];
$indexNumber = $_POST["indexNumber"];
}

function registerUser(){
    global $mysqli, $name, $surname, $login, $password, $groupNumber, $indexNumber;
    $passwordHash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO user (name, surname, login, password, groupNumber, indexNumber) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("ssssss", $name, $surname, $login, $passwordHash, $groupNumber, $indexNumber);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close(); 
}



function usernameAvailable(){
    global $mysqli, $login, $count;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = ?";
    if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)){
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $login);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $count = $stmt->num_rows;
    $stmt->close();
    }
    if($count < 1){
        return true;
    }
    else 
        return false;
}
    $response = "false";

if(usernameAvailable()){
    registerUser();
    $response = "true";
}echo json_encode($response);
$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: If it's catching an error while parsing the JSON response, there's probably something non-JSON in the response. What does this line tell you? `Log.d("RA", response);` Does the log display a valid JSON string?

Comment: With this:

  $response = array();
    $response["success"] = false;
 
 
 if(usernameAvailable()){
  registerUser();
  $response["success"] = true;
 }

Im getting back from my Php file:

{"success":true}

Loooks like a valid JSON response to me tough

Comment: Yes, but is that also what your Android app is *actually* receiving from your server? What is the *literal* `response` string you're logging from your Android code?

Comment: https://i.snag.gy/sg7LFW.jpg


That's what im getting in the Android monitor

Comment: Ok. If you change this line: `Log.d("RA", "catch");` to add `e` as a third parameter, what is the error message?

Comment: https://i.snag.gy/IL7u5Q.jpg

Here it is.

Comment: Right, so the problem is not with parsing the JSON string, the problem is with this line: `String success = jsonResponse.getString(response);`. Based on the JSON response, you probably want `boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");` **Edit** Let me expand upon that in an answer.

Comment: Oh my god, I'm retarded. 

I was using 
boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean(response);
Instead of ("success") as an argument. Thank you very much for your help. Really appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try assigning the return from `mysqli->prepare()` to a variable and testing that is returning true before proceeding to the actual database actions. Using a try/catch method it might help identify if there is a problem in the php.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
require("Password.php");

try{

    $mysqli = new mysqli( "localhost", "id2147309_javaprojekt123", "javaprojekt321", "id2147309_javaprojekt" );

    if( $mysqli->connect_errno ){
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    }

    if( isset( $_POST["name"], $_POST["surname"], $_POST["login"], $_POST["password"], $_POST["groupNumber"], $_POST["indexNumber"] ) ){
        $name = $_POST["name"];
        $surname= $_POST["surname"];
        $login = $_POST["login"];
        $password = $_POST["password"];
        $groupNumber = $_POST["groupNumber"];
        $indexNumber = $_POST["indexNumber"];
    }


    function registerUser(){
        global $mysqli, $name, $surname, $login, $password, $groupNumber, $indexNumber;
        $passwordHash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `user` ( `name`, `surname`, `login`, `password`, `groupNumber`, `indexNumber` ) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

        if( $stmt ){
            $stmt->bind_param( "ssssss", $name, $surname, $login, $passwordHash, $groupNumber, $indexNumber );
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();
            return true;
        } else {
            throw new Exception( 'Failed to prepare sql query in: ' . __FUNCTION__ );
        }
        return false;
    }
    function usernameAvailable(){
        global $mysqli, $login, $count;
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` = ?';
        $stmt=$mysqli->prepare( $sql );

        if( $stmt ){
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $login);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();
            $count = $stmt->num_rows;
            $stmt->close();
        } else {
            throw new Exception( 'Failed to prepare sql query in: ' . __FUNCTION__ );
        }
        return $count==0 ? true : false;
    }


    $available = call_user_func('usernameAvailable');
    $response = $available ? call_user_func('registerUser') : false;
    $mysqli->close();

    echo json_encode( $response );

}catch( Exception $e ){
    echo json_encode( array(
        'success'   =>  false,
        'Exception' =>  $e->getMessage()
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in this line:

```
String success = jsonResponse.getString(response);
```

Your JSON string is this:

```
{"success":true}
```

Parsing this will create a JSONObject with one key/value pair: "success" = boolean true

What you're trying to do here, is get the String value of the key `response` (which is the full `{"success":true}` string, which does NOT exist as a key in the JSONObject). Instead, you should use `jsonResponse.getString("success")` because "success" is actually the key you're interested in.

However, since it's actually a boolean value and not a String, you should not use `getString()` but use `getBoolean()` instead:

```
boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
```

This will have an impact on your following `if`-statement as well:

```
if (success == "success") {
```

should become:

```
if (success) {
```

(because `success` is now a boolean `true` or `false`).

Comment: You're entirely right and that was the problem. Thanks again :)

Comment: @PiotrOlech - say thank you is by accepting the answer, and upvoting it in this case. This will help others with a similar question.